# How to await promise.all when editing message with embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have next code:

```
let usersThatReacted = [];
  fetchMsg.reactions.cache.map(async (reaction) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name !== '') return;
    let reactedUsers = await reaction.users.fetch();
    reactedUsers.map((user) => {
      usersThatReacted.push(db.get(user.id));
    });
    message.channel.send(await (Promise.all(usersThatReacted))); //here i have message from bot with users..
  });
```

And it works perfectly, bot waiting ("awaiting") until all of requests in db will be complete, and after that it sending a message with array of users who reacted on message..

**But how to do the same thing with command which editing message with embed?**

I mean:

```
let usersThatReacted = [];
    message.reactions.cache.map(async (reaction) => {
      if (reaction.emoji.name !== '') return;
      let reactedUsers = await reaction.users.fetch();
      reactedUsers.map((user) => {
        usersThatReacted.push(db.get(user.id));
      });
     
    });

message.channel.messages.fetch(message.id).then(message => {
  const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setAuthor('.: Отметки активности :.', 'https://emojigraph.org/media/microsoft/crossed-swords_2694-fe0f.png')
    .addFields(
      { name: '', value: `${usersThatReacted}`, inline: true }, //but here code dont waiting until "usersThatReacted" (array) will be complete(
    )
  message.edit(exampleEmbed)
    .then(msg => console.log(`Updated the content of a message to ${msg.content}`))
    .catch(console.error);
})
```

When i deleted `message.channel.send(await (Promise.all(usersThatReacted)));`

i've got error "RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.", what means this part of code (with sending editing message) dont waiting until array is complete..

When put `` value: `${(await (Promise.all(usersThatReacted)))}`, `` instead of `` value: `${usersThatReacted}`, ``
I’ve got error: await is undefined

Comment: What is happening instead? Any errors/problems?

Comment: Yea, editing post alredy. 
I already tried "message.edit(await (Promise.all(exampleEmbed)))" but same error(

Comment: "*And it works perfectly*" - no it doesn't. If there are multiple `reaction`s in the `message.reactions.cache` you're mapping over (I don't know discord - is the cache an array?), it will send multiple things to `message.channel` with unpredictable amounts of `usersThatReacted`.

Comment: Right, perfectly) I’ve got something like:  sets Mike, John, Den, Rose. And then I wanna see “who reacted on message ?” I type some command like: “!who” and bot send me: Mike John Den Rose. And ur right, it’s array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over here you are not waiting for the promises to resolve.

```js
addFields({ 
    name: '', 
    value: `${usersThatReacted}`, 
    inline: true 
})
```

You need to use `Promise.all` there.

```js
addFields({ 
    name: '', 
    value: `${(await (Promise.all(usersThatReacted)))}`, 
    inline: true 
})
```

Comment: Alredy tried it, but had error:
/home/index.js:153   { name: '', value: `${await Promise.all(usersThatReacted)}`, inline: true },
SyntaxError: Missing } in template expression.  
And markers (^^^^) set on "await" word

Comment: Now (with new “(“ and “)” have err: “await is not defined”

Comment: I’ve already tried insert new variable (like: let test = await Promise.all(usersThatReacted), but in embed I have same error)

Comment: Editing post with last attempts and errors